# Regex question regarding string matching

Tags: regex

How would I match the string contained inside these brackets using regex?

```
[youtubehd:JqIrKJ1Q1nz]
```

I would like replace the contents after the `:` and before the bracket.

The end result would look like this

```
http://www.youtube.com/JqIrKJ1Q1nz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Match:                   Replace:
/\[youtubehd:(\w+)\]/    http://www.youtube.com/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample Perl code:

```
my $string='[youtubehd:JqIrKJ1Q1nz]';
my $result;
if ($string =~ /\[youtubehd:([^\]]+)\]/) {
  $result= "http://www.youtube.com/$1";
}
```

This regex works even if the string contains special characters.